# CSS select based on logical hierarchy

Tags: jquery, html, css

HTML tags with the `.container` class form a logical hierarchy in my case like this:

```
<div class="container" data-id="1">
    Level 1 #1
    <div>abc</div>
    <div class="container" data-id="1">
        Level 2 #1
        <div>other div container
            <div class="container" data-id="1">
                Level 3 #1
            </div>
            <div class="container" data-id="2">
                Level 3 #2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>other div container
        <div>other div container
            <div class="container" data-id="2">
                Level 2 #2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container" data-id="2">
    Level 1 #2
</div>
```

Now I would like to select an element in the hierarchy based on path elements of that hierarchy with jQuery like this:

```
$('.container[data-id="1"] .container[data-id="2"]').css("color", "red");
```

As a result I would like to have `Level 2 #2` to be red instead of `Level 3 #2`.

I tried to use the `:not()` selector like in this jsFiddle but it didn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/zwg8cbg3/

Is there any solution with a jQuery CSS selector?

Comment: If there is no simple solution like using a one line CSS selector I could iterate over the result of `$('.container[data-id="1"] .container[data-id="2"]')` and use the one that has the amount of parent `.container` elements that correspond to the level of the hierarchy (minus one as the current one would not be a parent). It would be one parent `.container` element for `.container[data-id="2"]` in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the direct sibling selector:

```
$('.container[data-id="1"] > div > .container[data-id="2"]').css("color", "red");
```

**Snippet**

```js
$('.container[data-id="1"] > div > .container[data-id="2"]').css("color", "red");
```

```css
div {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" data-id="1">
  Level 1 #1
  <div>abc</div>
  <div class="container" data-id="1">
    Level 2 #1
    <div>other div container
      <div class="container" data-id="1">
        Level 3 #1
      </div>
      <div class="container" data-id="2">
        Level 3 #2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>other div container
    <div>other div container
      <div class="container" data-id="2">
        Level 2 #2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container" data-id="2">
  Level 1 #2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is no answer yet it's implemented like that:

```
var cssSelector = "";
var ids = this.scriptStack.split("_");
$(ids).each(function(){
    cssSelector+=".container[data-id='"+this+"'] ";
});
$('...').find(cssSelector).each(function(){
    if($(this).parents('.container').size() == ids.length-1) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

But of course it's not good to first select to many elements and then needing to search for the right one.